# delete files from a particular folder automatically in aws s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to delete files from s3 bucket. Inside `test` bucket, there is a folder named `mi` and inside mi `archive`.
I configured `life cycle rule` on `test` bucket to delete file `abc.txt` from `test/mi/archive/abc.txt` after 7 days. I want to delete only `abc.txt` but it deletes full `archive` folder not only file.
At the time of rule apply on `test` bucket, I gave prefix `mi/archive/`.

Comment: Can you show your lifecycle policy?

Answer (score 2):

S3 doesn't have folders, only object key prefixes. If there is no object with `mi/archive` in the prefix then that "folder" is not going to appear.

This really shouldn't be an issue. The next time you upload an object with `mi/archive` prefix in the key the "folder" will appear again.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all for giving suggestion....

Finally, I got a solution. I did some **changes** in **prefix**. In place of **"mi/archive"**, i gave files starting letters because my all files starts with **"cd"**. Suppose there is a file named **"cd_abcd.txt"**. So at the time of rule configuration on **"test"** bucket, i putted prefix **"mi/archive/cd"**.  So after **7 days**, only files will be delete not full **"archive"** folder.

Comment: oh thank you so much! Looks like this would work! I have been trying "mi/archive/cd*" which obviously doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

lifecycling is only for the entire folder/bucket. Your best/cheapest bet is probably a scheduled lambda to check for the file, it's creation date, and delete if necessary.