# AWS configuration to delete files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a folder "Execution" folder in s3 bucket.

It has folders and files like

```
Execution

    Exec_06-06-2022/
        file1.json
        file2.json
    Exec_07-06-2022/
        file3.json
        file4.json
```

I need to configure to delete the Exec_datestamp folders and the inside files after X days.

I tried this using AWS lifecycle config for the prefix "Execution/"

But it deletes the folder Execution/ after X days ( set this to 1 day to test)

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There are no folders in S3. `Execution` is part of objects name, specifically its [key prefix](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-keys.html#object-key-guidelines). The S3 console only makes `Execution` to appear as a folder, but there is no such thing in S3. So your lifecycle deletes `Execution/` object (not folder), because it matches your query.

You can try with `Execution/Exec*` filter.

Comment: Execution/Exec* , where do I set this, if I set this in prefix, it takes literally as "Execution/Exec*"

Comment: @Rakesh The same place you setup your prefix "Execution/".

Answer (score 0):

Got it, https://stackoverflow.com/a/41459761/5010582. The prefix has to be "Execution/Exec" without any wildcard.